# Prove that the set of all differentiable functions :[0,1]→ [0,1] is uncountable.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives, first-countable

Prove that the set of all differentiable functions :[0,1]→ [0,1] is uncountable.

In my notes, I have something like:

Consider $x \in {[0,1]}$, $f_{x} (t) = x$ for all $t$ .
$\{h_{x} | x ∈ [0,1] \}= |[0,1]| = c$ .

I have no idea what this means. Can anyone explain or help me prove it?

Comment: Take $f=c$, $c\in{[0,1]}$.

Comment: Every constant function is differentiable and there is one-to-one relation between $[0,1]$ and constant functions $[0,1]\to[0,1]$.

Comment: @dmtri : Isn’t this exactly what OP quotes from his notes?

Comment: @MPW,  actually yes,  but after editing the question... I gave first a hint and then I edited it,  realising that it is the same...) :

Comment: Some other concern. I think you missed a cardinality sign for the set you describe in your question.) :

Answer (score 5):

For each $x \in [0,1]$ define $f_x(t)=x$ for all $t \in [0,1]$. This gives you an element $f_x$ of your set since constant functions are differentiable. The map $x \to f_x$ is one to one ($f_x=f_y$ implies $f_x(0)=f_y(0)$ which means $x=y$) and $[0,1]$ is uncountable. Hence the given set is also uncountable.

Answer (score 1):

Actually,  some concerns... It is not for all $t$ but for $t\in{[0, 1]}$. Second for the set described in your question,  it assumes the constant functions describes in the comments. Third,  the $c$ in your question is the continoum symbol.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the other answers:

- Each value in $[0,1]$ defines a distinct constant function
- Each of these constant functions is differentiable
- The collection of these functions has the same cardinality as $[0,1]$ since the functions are all distinct
- The cardinality of $[0,1]$ is the uncountable cardinal $\mathfrak c$